# php_pdo_mysql.dll not configuring after uncommenting in php.ini file

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

Referencing this site: https://www.drupal.org/requirements/pdo I made the following changes to my `php.ini` file.

> Windows users: For Apache, you will need to make sure php_pdo.dll and
>   php_pdo_mysql.dll exist in the php/ext directory, un-comment or add
>   the appropriate lines in php.ini, and restart the web server.  Under
>   Windows, it may no longer be required to enable PDO when using newer
>   versions of PHP, namely, PHP version 5.3 and later. This refers to
>   php_pdo.dll. However, you still need to activate php_pdo_mysql.dll for
>   MySQL or for whichever database you're using

`php_pdo_mysql.dll` has been uncommented in my `php.ini` file, `extension_dir` has been set equal to `C:\php\ext`, which is where the extensions are located at and the web server has been restarted. However, my `phpinfo()` page still does not show that `php_pdo_mysql` has been configured. I am using Windows 7 64-bit, with Apache 2.4.16 Win64 and PHP 5.6 (5.6.11) (VC11 x64 Thread Safe binary from http://windows.php.net/download/).

Any help with this seemingly simple problem would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue has been resolved. I had set up a system path variable to C:\PHP without realizing that libmysql.dll was not in that particular folder! Thanks for the help Santosh, I appreciate you taking the time to try to help me out!

Answer (score 0):

On a windows server you can add the following lines in your php.ini

```
extension=php_pdo.dll
extension=php_pdo_mysql.dll
```

On a Linux server you can compile php with the following option --with-pdo-mysql In your php.ini, add the following lines

```
extension=pdo.so
extension=pdo_mysql.so
```

and restart the server.
which server you are using widows or linux. Also check PDO and PDO_MYSQL installed or not

Comment: I am using Windows, and my php.ini file already contains the extension php_pdo_MySQL.dll. The other extension did not come with the download and from my limited understanding is already included. The server has also been restarted.

Comment: Check with phpinfo() to ensure that the path for the php.ini is the same one being set. On Windows machines it is common for multiple instances of php.ini to be created and cause confusion. Also, calling php from the command line will give you an error message with more details as to why it may not be loading. It might be that the extension that you are trying to include is not compatible with your PHP installation.

Comment: Try php -m in console, it will show startup errors of PHP.  check link http://www.apachelounge.com/viewtopic.php?p=21034

Comment: Each time I edit the php.ini file, I make sure to use "Save as" php.ini, so that it doesn't save as an INI-DEVELOPMENT or INI-PRODUCTION file. Here is a picture of my php-info page. http://www.mediafire.com/view/9kc8rm8kwhif89x/php-info.PNG

Comment: 1) In your php.ini change 

2) display_startup_errors to On 

3) try to run php from the command line 

4) C:\path\to\php.exe -m

Comment: Okay, I changed display_startup_errors to On. What should I type in the command line? This is php -m:

Comment: I have also added ;C:\php to my System variable Path.

Comment: try restarting server

Comment: I have done that multiple times, and just rebooted. Frustrating issue for sure.